# Google Sheets Script: Function Not Being Called

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use the onEdit function to determine when a "parameter" cell with a dropdown list has been edited. They are each a single cell in a Named Range.

In previous testing, this works AOK, successfully calling functions "c_SetUserDefinedAngles()" and "c_SetUserProperties()" via the switch statement.

I have now added another case "Drag_Induced_Model_AspectRatio". The alert prior to calling function c_AspectRatio() works.

However, the alert in function c_AspectRatio() does show up, although it does if I run it via Debug.  What's more, I tried the Logger as well, and get a TypeError as descibed in the code comments.

I also tried commenting out all code in c_AspectRatio() except for the Alert and Logger, but the function is still not working - somehow the function is not being "entered". Has anyone something I can try pls?

```
function onEdit(e) {
// Author: Max Hugen
// Date: 20102-11-04
// Purpose: Direct Edits to required functions if applicable
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var target_sheet = "Analysis";
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  
  // Exit script ASAP if not calling a function for a specified sheet & range
  if (sheet != target_sheet) { return; }
  
  // All cells using functions are Named Ranges. Run appropriate function if found.
  var cellNamedRange = c_GetRangeName(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation()); // Custom function, see below.
    //ui.alert("onEdit \r\n cellNamedRange is: " + cellNamedRange + " ---- or if nothing, not a Named Range!");
  if (cellNamedRange == "") { return; }  // Exit if cell is NOT a Named Range
  
  switch(cellNamedRange) { 

    case "User_Course" :
      c_SetUserDefinedAngles(cellNamedRange);
      break;
      
    case "User_TWA" : // note this continues down
    case "User_AWA" : // note this continues down
    case "User_SA" :
      c_SetUserProperties();
      break;
      
    case "Drag_Induced_Model_AspectRatio" :
        ui.alert("onEdit \r\n\ Switch case found for " + cellNamedRange);
      c_AspectRatio(Drag_Induced_Model_AspectRatio);
      break;
    
    case "Drag_Induced_Model_Cdi" :
      c_InducedDrag(Drag_Induced_Model_Cdi);
      break;
    
    default:
      ui.alert("Function onEdit: Switch case NOT entered for " + cellNamedRange);
  }  

  return;
}

function c_AspectRatio(modelAR) {
// Author: Max Hugen
// Date: 20102-11-20
// Purpose: Calculate Aspect Ratio, using different models, 
//          due to inconsistences in calcs!

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("c_AspectRatio: \r\n\ Entered function");
  //TypeError: Logger.Log is not a function at c_AspectRatio(Drag:10:10)
  Logger.Log("c_AspectRatio: \r\n\ Entered function");

/*
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Analysis")
  var formula = "";
  
  switch(modelAR) { 
    case "Original" :
        ui.alert("c_AspectRatio \r\n\ Switch case found for " + modelAR);
      // Equation:  AR = s^2 / A
      formula = "= POWER(Data!$C$30, 2) / E6";
      sheet.getRange('AR6').setFormula(formula);
      sheet.getRange('AR6').copyTo(sheet.getRange('AR7:AR29'));

      break;
      
    default:
      ui.alert("Function c_AspectRatio: Switch case NOT found for " + modelAR);
  return;
  
  }
*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by

> the alert in function c_AspectRatio() does show up, although it does if I run it via Debug

But as for the type error:

You have a small typo - it should be  `Logger.log` and not  `Logger.Log`.

Comment: Thanks re the typo, I didn't realise it was case sensitive. The Logger now works! So I'm definitely "in" the function c_AspectRatio(), so that's excellent. I still don't understand why the Alert doesn't work though - it is in a different script file than the onEdit, would that affect it?

Comment: Weird, the function stopped again.Logger.log not working now, Alert still not working, Again, I commented out all of the other code in the function. BUT, I can "run" it from the script window.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by different script, but `getUi()` only works for bound scripts and only for the spreadsheet which is bound to the script where `getUi()´ is being called.

Comment: Yes, it is a bound script. I use it frequently to help me debug my code, as I'm still learning. By "different script" I meant a "script file", within this one spreadsheet. I break up functionality into different script files in the "project" (?) so it's easier to find related functions.

Comment: There is no problem with break up your functions into different script files - as long as you don't have more than one function with the same name (applies also to onEdit). If your function works when called manually, but not on onEdit - either it is not being called because of the limitations of the onEdit trigger (go to View->Executions and see) or because you do not enter the correct case. Mind also that the trigger only fires on human edits.